# Solutions for creating a PDF/A-3a

Tags: pdf-a

I am required to produce a PDF/A-3a document for my thesis. I know there are a couple of questions and anwers already about this topic in TeX.SE, but they're generally quite old and I haven't found good answers on this particular topic.

Some people suggested to use the `pdfx` package, but it was also said that it has some issues. So what is the best option for creating a PDF/A-3a as of now? Could you please make an example? I'm using pdflatex as compiler.

Comment: `A-3a` requires the pdf to be tagged. This can be done currently only with the experimental/research package tagpdf, which requires also the use of the pdfmanagement-testphase package. You should then use lualatex as paragraph tagging doesn't work yet with pdflatex. `A-3b`  can be achieved with pdfx and also with the pdfmanagement-testphase package.

Answer (score 3):

Following the comment by @ulrike-fischer, I was able to validate a basic example using LuaLaTeX and the following packages: `pdfmanagement-testphase`, `axessibility`, and `pdfx`. I never used any of those before so maybe we don't need them all.

```
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}
\DeclareDocumentMetadata{
    pdfversion=1.7,
}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{mybook,
    author={Some Author},
    date={2021},
    title={Some title},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tagpdf]{axessibility} 
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fixpdfx}  % See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/606007
\usepackage[a-3a]{pdfx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\hypersetup{draft}  % Disable hyperlinks.

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\title{My title}
\author{My author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Lorem ipsum \autocite{mybook}.

\blindmathpaper

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I had to disable hyperlinks with `\hypersetup{draft}`. Without this line, the validation fails with this message:

> Specification: ISO 19005-3:2012, Clause: 6.3.2, Test number: 1
>
> Except for annotation dictionaries whose Subtype value is Popup, all
> annotation dictionaries shall contain the F key.

I did not try any tables or figures.

Comment: I just tried the figure (and patch) from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/609120/190398 and it works too.

Comment: pdfmanagement and pdfx are not compatible, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/609351/2388