# How can we get hyperlinks to pass the PDF/A-3a validation?

Tags: pdf-a

The following example is from a reply to [Solutions for creating a PDF/A-3a](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/599958/solutions-for-creating-a-pdf-a-3a)

Hyperlinks were disabled with `\hypersetup{draft}` to pass the PDF/A-3a validation (in veraPDF=. Without this line, the validation fails with this message:

> Specification: ISO 19005-3:2012, Clause: 6.3.2, Test number: 1
>
> Except for annotation dictionaries whose Subtype value is Popup, all
> annotation dictionaries shall contain the F key.

Any suggestions on how get links that pass the validation?

```
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}
\DeclareDocumentMetadata{
    pdfversion=1.7,
}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{mybook,
    author={Some Author},
    date={2021},
    title={Some title},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tagpdf]{axessibility} 
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fixpdfx}  % See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/606007
\usepackage[a-3a]{pdfx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\hypersetup{draft}  % Disable hyperlinks.

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\title{My title}
\author{My author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Lorem ipsum \autocite{mybook}.

\blindmathpaper

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: you can't use pdfx along with the pdfmanagement. pdfx is not compatible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(updated october 2023 to the new state of the project)

- pdfx is not compatible with the pdfmanagement.
- hyperxmp is not compatible either. xmp-metadata are provided by the pdfmanagement.
- The pdfmanagement allows to set a pdfstandard, but in the current version A-3a is not supported.
- I have now added a first, preliminary support for A-3a, so with the *next* pdfmanagement version (0.95i) the document below will pass validation.
- The axessibility package does *not* create a tagged pdf. It only tags a bit the math. All the rest is tagged as artifact. From the point of accessibility this is quite useless. Also the package is no longer compatible with a current version of tagpdf.
- you can try to activate more tagging as shown in the document with the testphase option and `testphase=phase-II` or `\testphase=phase-III` but be aware that in a real document lots of things can fail.

```
\DocumentMetadata{pdfstandard=A-3a,
    pdfversion=1.7,
    testphase=phase-II, %activates paratagging
    %debug={para=show,uncompress}
}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{mybook,
    author={Some Author},
    date={2021},
    title={Some title},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftitle=mytitle}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\title{My title}
\author{My author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Lorem ipsum \autocite{mybook}.

\blindmathpaper

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, Ulrike.